# Separating data if time difference is 24 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, ssms

I am having one table like below,

| id | giftcard_id | downltime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 6 | 23-03-2017 |
| 1111 | 7 | 01-04-2017 |
| 1111 | 7 | 02-04-2017 |
| 1111 | 7 | 05-05-2017 |
| 1111 | 7 | 06-05-2017 |
| 1111 | 7 | 07-05-2017 |
| 1111 | 7 | 08-05-2017 |
| 1111 | 7 | 11-05-2017 |
| 2222 | 8 | 21-07-2018 |
| 2222 | 8 | 22-07-2018 |
| 2222 | 8 | 23-07-2018 |
| 2222 | 8 | 28-09-2019 |

I want the giftcard record in separate row if time difference is more that 24 hrs (1 day). I want the output like below,

| id | giftcard_id | startTime | endTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 6 | 23-03-2017 | 23-03-2017 |
| 1111 | 7 | 01-04-2017 | 02-04-2017 |
| 1111 | 7 | 05-05-2017 | 08-05-2017 |
| 1111 | 7 | 11-05-2017 | 11-05-2017 |
| 2222 | 8 | 21-07-2018 | 23-07-2018 |
| 2222 | 8 | 28-09-2019 | 28-09-2019 |

Comment: Just checking why 21-07 till 23-07 isnt a single recrod, as they represent consecutive time gaps

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph, my bad. 21 to 23 should be in one row. you are correct

Comment: @DaleK, I tried to do by using LAG but it doesn't work

Comment: @Ali so show us

Answer (score 0):

It is called the island and gap problem.

You can use the analytical function and aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT ID, GIFTCARDID, 
       MIN(DOWNLTIME) AS STARTTIME, 
       MAX(DOWNLTIME) AS ENDTIME 
  FROM (SELECT T.*, 
               SUM(CASE WHEN DOWNLTIME = DATEADD(DAY,1,LG) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)  
                    OVER (PARTITION BY ID, GIFTCARDID ORDER BY DOWNLTIME) AS SM 
          FROM (SELECT T.*, 
                       LAG(DOWNLTIME) 
                         OVER (PARTITION BY ID, GIFTCARDID ORDER BY DOWNLTIME) AS LG
                  FROM YOUR_TABLE T) T
        )
  GROUP BY ID, GIFTCARDID, SM
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this using the tabibitosan method

```
with data
  as (
select *
 from (values
      (1111,6,convert(date,'23-03-2017',105))
    ,(1111,7 ,convert(date,'01-04-2017',105))
    ,(1111,7 ,convert(date,'02-04-2017',105))
    ,(1111,7 ,convert(date,'05-05-2017',105))
    ,(1111,7 ,convert(date,'06-05-2017',105))
    ,(1111,7 ,convert(date,'07-05-2017',105))
    ,(1111,7 ,convert(date,'08-05-2017',105))
    ,(1111,7 ,convert(date,'11-05-2017',105))
    ,(2222,8 ,convert(date,'21-07-2018',105))
    ,(2222,8 ,convert(date,'22-07-2018',105))
    ,(2222,8 ,convert(date,'23-07-2018',105))
    ,(2222,8 ,convert(date,'28-09-2019',105))
    )t(id,giftcardid,downltime)
     )
 select id
       , giftcardid
       , min(downltime) as starttime
       , max(downltime) as endtime
from (
        select id
               , giftcardid
               , downltime
               , row_number() over(partition by id order by downltime) as rnk
               , dateadd(day,-row_number() over(partition by id order by downltime),downltime) as grp_val
          from data
     )x
group by x.id
       , x.giftcardid
       , x.grp_val


+------+------------+------------+------------+
|  id  | giftcardid | starttime  |  endtime   |
+------+------------+------------+------------+
| 1111 |          6 | 2017-03-23 | 2017-03-23 |
| 1111 |          7 | 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-02 |
| 1111 |          7 | 2017-05-05 | 2017-05-08 |
| 1111 |          7 | 2017-05-11 | 2017-05-11 |
| 2222 |          8 | 2018-07-21 | 2018-07-23 |
| 2222 |          8 | 2019-09-28 | 2019-09-28 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+
```